Change checkbox label in event form
On the event form, there is a checkbox called Public Event. I would like to change to something else. But it seems there is no hook to do this:
$this->addElement('checkbox', 'is_public', ts('Public Event')); 

Could anyone confirm if it's possible without use JavaScript?

Yes possible to do it using build form hook, but you will still need to play around with the label of the field because its a checkbox and is written differently. So using JS you will need to replace the section with correct format.
/**
 * Implements hook_civicrm_buildForm().
 *
 * @link https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm
 */
function cisitepasswords_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  if ($formName == 'CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_EventInfo') {
    if ($form->elementExists('is_public')) {
      $form->removeElement('is_public');
      $form->addYesNo('is_public', ts('Public Event')); 
    }
  }
}


You could use the Word Replacement feature with no code to change the string 'Public Event' to something else.
Here's a link to the documentation: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/customizing-the-user-interface/#using-word-replacement-to-change-terminology

This seems like it would be a much simpler solution

@Coleman could you give me an example?

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/customizing-the-user-interface/#using-word-replacement-to-change-terminology
